# Errors related to webpack and babel-node with react, express app

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm really struggling with this.

I would like to implement SSR to improve SEO for my app, and I am stuck.

I used CRA for the client side and express for the server.

webpack is successfully compiling the client, but when I run everything, I get errors related to my static files like less (I'm using Ant Design, FWIW) and SVG.

I feel like I have tried just about every possible permutation and nothing seems to be working, so I think I may be missing something fundamental.

My webpack.config.js file is:

```
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  entry: ['babel-polyfill','./client/src/index.js'],
  output: {
    path: path.resolve('public'),
    filename: 'bundle.js'
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
                "@babel/preset-env",
                "@babel/preset-react"
            ]
          }
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.less$/, // match any .less file, 
        use: [
          {loader: 'style-loader'},
          {loader: 'css-loader'},
          { loader: "less-loader",
            options: {
              lessOptions: {
                modifyVars: { 
                  '@primary-color': '#0a1f8f',
                  '@secondary-color': '#124734',
                  '@tertiary-color': '#e04403',
                  '@info-color': '@primary-color',
                  '@success-color': '#124734',
                  '@processing-color': '@primary-color',
                  '@error-color': 'rgba(224, 20, 7, 1.0)',
                  '@highlight-color': '#f6dfa4',
                  '@warning-color': 'rgba(224, 20, 7, 1.0)',
                  '@normal-color': '#231f20',
                  '@white': '#fff',
                  '@black': '#231f20',
                  '@layout-header-background': '#231f20',
                  '@layout-header-color': '#f6dfa4'
                  },
                  javascriptEnabled: true
              }
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      
      {
        test: /\.(s*)css$/, // match any .scss or .css file, 
        use: [
          { loader: "style-loader" }, 
          { loader: "css-loader" }
        ]
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/i,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'file-loader',
          },
        ],
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

My babel.config.js is:

```
module.exports = {
    "presets": ['@babel/preset-react', ['@babel/preset-env', {
        targets: {
          "browsers": ["last 2 versions"],
          node: "current"
        }
      }]],
    "plugins": [["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"], ["@babel/plugin-transform-runtime", {
        "regenerator": true
      }]]
}
```

My file structure is:
/server/...
/client/...
and my npm commands are (I have tried both, and neither works):

"dev": "NODE_ENV=development webpack -wd & NODE_ENV=development nodemon --exec babel-node ./server/server.js --ignore public",
"server": "nodemon --exec babel-node ./server/server.js NODE_ENV=development --ignore public"

Here's an example of an error I receive:

```
@import '~antd/dist/antd.less';
^

SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token
```

Also, if it helps, when I run dev, I get an error from babel-node BEFORE webpack is done compiling.
Thanks in advance!

One other thing. The error is introduced when I import my App.js file into my serverRender file like so:

```
const React = require('react');
const ReactDOMServer = require('react-dom/server');
const { StaticRouter } = require('react-router-dom');

const App = require('../client/src/App'); // <!-- commenting out this line and the error is removed, but of course that doesn't solve anything

const ky = require('ky/umd');

const serverRender = (req, sport, year, season, gameWeek, query, page, url, id) => {
    console.log('req', req)
    return ReactDOMServer.renderToString(
        React.createElement(
            'div',
            null,
            `Rendered on the server at ${new Date()}`
        )
    )
}

module.exports = {serverRender};
```